# Margin: 0 auto positioning not working on divs

Tags: html, css

For some strange reason, centering divs using margin: 0 auto is not working. My code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Picture Gallery</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/week7.css">

</head>

<body>

<h1>The Mighty Avengers</h1>



<div class="slide1">
    <img src="images/hawkeye.jpg" alt="Hawkeye" />
    <img src="images/capmar.jpg" alt="Captain Marvel" />
    <img src="images/beast.gif" alt="Beast" />
    <img src="images/thor.jpg" alt="Thor" />
</div>

 <div class="slide2">
    <img src="images/cap.jpg" alt="Captain America" />
    <img src="images/ant.jpg" alt="Ant Man" />
    <img src="images/vision.jpg" alt="The Vision" />
    <img src="images/scar.jpg" alt="Scarlet Witch" />
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

and CSS:

```
html {
background-color: gray;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
}

img {

height: 250px;
margin-left: -20px;
width: 250px;
}

.slide1, .slide2 {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 85%;
}
```

None of the other instances of this type of centering talked about on Stack have been any help. I've tried this with and without a display type set on the classes, to no avail. Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your image is 150px.. and your div is 80% of the document

You can fix it doing a text-align: center; on .slide1, .slide2.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `margin: 0 auto;` is working in your case but the problem is another - The images width is not enough to full fill the container, so if you want to center the images here is a code for it:

```
img:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.slide1, .slide2 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That did not occur to me, and that is indeed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you looking for:

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/3k8f9491/)</kbd>**

**HTML**: No Change

**CSS**

```
html {
background-color: gray;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
}

img {

height: 250px;
margin-left: -2px; /* So that it resides side by side*/
width: 250px;
}

.slide1, .slide2 {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 500px; /* As you are having 250px for each image */        
}
```

Comment: @Michael Sean Caveney, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are trying to achieve? Your slide divs are centered. I've applied a yellow border to them so that you can see.

```
.slide1, .slide2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 85%;
  border:1px solid yellow;
}
```

I've also updated your img css to make it more responsive so that the images dont wrap onto a second row.

```
img {
  height: auto;
  width: 25%;
  max-width:250px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmmb03ck/4/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the "colored border to see that your containers are where they need to be" trick. I'm kicking myself for forgetting that, it's been a while since i had to write CSS.